# Simplest Way To Install .clr File on OSX?

Tags: xcode, macos, installation, color-picker

I just created a .clr palette and want to share it with people who aren't tech-savvy, or comfortable using terminal. I was wondering if there is a script or way of packaging it up, so that mavericks moves it into the proper directory when double-clicked.

Background: I'm an iOS developer but have never developed anything for osx, so I do have Xcode installed if it's required for what I need.

I know that in terminal I could just use `sudo mv` but is there a simpler way without using terminal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an installer package is the de facto standard on OS X for this kind of thing. It's the most straightforward and professional means to get the right files in exactly the right places.

The standard command-line tools for building installer packages are:

- [**pkgbuild**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html)
- [**productbuild**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html)

**DESCRIPTION**

**pkgbuild** - Is defined as a component package that contains a payload to be installed by the OS X Installer. Component packages can be installed independently, however, they are often incorporated into a product archive — along with a distribution and localized resources, using `productbuild`.

**productbuild** - Is defined as a product archive (which is a flat file with a .pkg extension). Productbuild creates a deployable product archive, which can be used with the OS X Installer. It can easily install files in targeted locations, only requiring the end user to enter their administrator password.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thank you very much. Just one quick question, I've managed to set a background image and title in my distribution.xml file, to set an icon, should I just drop the icon file into the resources folder and paste it into the package's get info icon file? I can't seem to find anything on setting an icon through the xml file. Thanks!

Comment: @KingPolygon, I usually just paste the icon in the get info, which seems to have worked well enough. I guess it wouldn't hurt to add it into the resources, although might be unnecessary. :)